# Android Spinner reselects itself to first value every half second

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

So, I have a spinner, populated with ~35 values.  If I select, say, the fifth item, then when it is selected, it does what it is supposed to do (populate a second spinner).  My problem is that shortly afterwards (<1/2 second) it reverts the values in the second spinner to what they would be if option 1 in the first spinner were selected.  The fifth item in the first spinner is still selected but it acts as though the first item gets selected twice per second.

I've tried everything I could find on this (barely anything) and nothing has worked so far.  This basically has me stuck on going further in my app.

Entire Code:

```
package com.nicotera.colton.londontransitguide;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.jsoup.*;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Attributes;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class RoutesActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {
    Spinner dirSpinner;
    Spinner routeSpinner;


static String [] namedDirections = new String [2];
private static final String TAG = "RoutesActivity";

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_routes);
    dirSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.route_direction_spinner); // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
    routeSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.route_name_spinner); // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
    routeSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.routes_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); // Apply the adapter to the spinner
    routeSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
}
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
        int pos, long id) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Item selected");
    //DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("00##");
    int tempPos = pos;
    Log.i(TAG, ("Position of selected item: " + tempPos));
    int routeSelected;
    if (tempPos < 17)
        routeSelected = (tempPos + 1);
    else if (tempPos >= 17 && tempPos < 29)
        routeSelected = (tempPos + 2);
    else
        routeSelected = (tempPos + 3);
    String temp;
    if (routeSelected < 10)
        temp = ("0") + routeSelected;
    else
        temp = ("") + routeSelected;
    String url = "http://www.ltconline.ca/WebWatch/MobileAda.aspx?r=" + temp;
    new MyInnerClass().execute(url);

}

public void directionSpinner (String directions []) {
    int temp;
    for (int i = 1; i <=2; i++)
    {
        temp = Integer.parseInt(directions[i]);
        if (temp == 1)
            namedDirections[(i-1)] = "Eastbound";
        else if (temp == 2)
            namedDirections[(i-1)] = "Northbound";
        else if (temp == 3)
            namedDirections[(i-1)] = "Southbound";
        else if (temp == 4)
            namedDirections[(i-1)] = "Westbound";               
    }
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_routes);

    dirSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    adapter.add(namedDirections[0]);
    adapter.add(namedDirections[1]);
    dirSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    Log.i(TAG, "spinner populated");
}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    // Another interface callback
}

class MyInnerClass extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    String [] directions = new String [3];
    String [] directionNames = new String [3];
    private static final String TAG = "RoutesActivity";
       @Override
       protected void onPreExecute() {
       super.onPreExecute();

       }

       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
       super.onPostExecute(result);
       RoutesActivity.this.directionSpinner(directions);
       }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try{
            Pattern routeDirPattern = Pattern.compile("\\&d=(\\d{1,2})");
            Connection conn = Jsoup.connect(params[0]);
            Document doc = conn.get();
            int i = 0;
            Elements routeLinks = doc.select("a[href]");
            for (Element routeLink : routeLinks) {
                i = (i + 1);
                String name = routeLink.text();
                Attributes attrs = routeLink.attributes();
                String href = attrs.get("href");
                Matcher m = routeDirPattern.matcher(href);
                if (m.find()) {
                        String number = m.group(1);
                        directions [i] = number;
                        directionNames [i] = name;
                        Log.i(TAG, directionNames [i]);
                }
            }
            }catch(Exception e){Log.d("doinbackground exception", e.toString());}

               return ("Done");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I spotted the problem, but I'm really annoyed because you have posted this question _again_. So good luck! (Using the debugger to walk through your code will solve this in no time.)

Comment: Actually I deleted my previous question, does that really count as a repost?

Comment: I noticed, why did you delete the original?

Comment: No activity/comments in five days even when I added information to it 3 days ago.

Comment: I realize it's disrespectful to the community, but it gets annoying when you're trying to learn a new skill and when you ask for help it doesn't get answered, and you aren't supposed to ask again.

Comment: I have posted a link to the [FAQ#bounty] and probably [ask] at least twice and this [Will I get shot if I delete a question and repost?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/35891/188646) explains that reposting in any form is _not acceptable_. The ultimate question is why don't you use the debugger?

Comment: Honestly I'm not 100% sure how the debugger works, I mean it's spotted some errors immediately before but now it isn't giving me anything...
Also I can't offer I bounty (and I would) because my rep is too low

Comment: I realize that setting a bounty isn't an option yet, but that's not your only course of action. Here is a guide on [using the debugger](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html) to get you started. I will give you a very big hint: Set a some break points in `onItemSelected()`, `onPostExecute()`, and `directionSpinner()`. You should notice the reason why the Spinner is reset every 1/2 second then.

Comment: Oh, I was using the same onselected listener for both without an if statement to check which one was clicked so it just thought that the first one was clicked.

Answer (score 1):

I was using the same onselected listener for both without an if statement to check which one was clicked so it just thought that the first one was clicked.

This is the corrected code:

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
        int pos, long id) {
    Spinner spnr = (Spinner) parent;
    Log.i(TAG, "Item selected");
    switch(parent.getId()) {
    case R.id.route_name_spinner:
    //DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("00##");
    int tempPos = pos;
    Log.i(TAG, ("Position of selected item: " + tempPos));
    int routeSelected;
    if (tempPos < 17)
        routeSelected = (tempPos + 1);
    else if (tempPos >= 17 && tempPos < 29)
        routeSelected = (tempPos + 2);
    else
        routeSelected = (tempPos + 3);
    String temp;
    if (routeSelected < 10)
        temp = ("0") + routeSelected;
    else
        temp = ("") + routeSelected;
    String url = "http://www.ltconline.ca/WebWatch/MobileAda.aspx?r=" + temp;
    new MyInnerClass().execute(url);
    case R.id.route_direction_spinner:

    }

}
```